# How can a drone take down a high-tension power line?

Tags: high-voltage, power-engineering, drone

This news article -- in which a drone reportedly took down the power grid in Mountain View CA -- caught my eye:

[Thursday night power outage the result of a drone crash](http://www.mountainview.gov/news/displaynews.asp?NewsID=1168&TargetID=9)

Despite the compelling photo of something melted and charred, I'm still wondering what really happened.  As best I understand things:

- If the drone touched one conductor it would have no effect.
- The conductors on a high tension line are spaced too far apart for a drone to span them (and thus cause a short).
- The conductors are too thick for a drone to cut through them.

So: how *could* a drone take down a high-voltage grid?  Of course, if you were feeling malicious, you could outfit your drone with a long wire with the express intent of causing a short, but I didn't see any evidence that this was the case.

Comment: *I didn't see any evidence that this was the case* - did you see *any* evidence except this article? Anyway, looks like off-topic.

Comment: Nothing to with electronic design - question should be closed.

Comment: @LeonHeller It has to do with electronic design of power grids. Question should remain open.

Comment: If the drone was large enough (some octos are pretty big), it could short something out. My bet is that the drone crashed into something sensitive at a grid mast.

Comment: You are probably overstating the category of transmission line damaged - it is likely a local area distribution one (a set of transformers removed from residential customers), not a long distance "high tension" line.  Take a look at the area on an aerial map - its very densely built without anything that look like large tower pylons.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Google Earth View supports your hypothesis -- I should have checked first.  The term "high-voltage wire" in the report made me think transmission lines, not distribution.  And a drone could span a pair of wires in the latter.

Comment: Upon reading the guidelines of the help center, I agree my question is off-topic: it's about electrical engineering, not electronic design.  But then the site should be called "Electronic Design" rather than "Electrical Engineering"!!  Hrrmph!  :)

Answer (score 3):

The supporting poles are critical places. Flying near an insulator can well be too much. An arc occurred and the remnants of the drone have polluted the insulator. Thats only a guess. Another possiblity: The pilot has climbed up to make his stucked toy free. Nobody has seen the pilot after the smoke  and fire ceased.

Comment: Yes, this sounds plausible. (and lol, lol, lol)

Comment: Will he qualify for a Darwin Award?